# How to read SERVER['REQUEST_URI full dynamic path?

Tags: php

The code below works well when we are at a url path `/sard/` e.g. `www.example.com/sard/`yet if my url goes to `www.example.com/sard/page2` it breaks.

```
<?php
$twitter = '';
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    case '/sard/':
        $twitter = 'example';
        break;
    case '/pie/':
        $twitter = 'example_2';
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
?>
```

How can I make it so that it always read the `uri` full dynamic path?

Comment: You need to use if (strpos($url, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) !== false) { //code
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strpos.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/sard') === 0){
    echo 'oke';
}
```

This will match all the urls who start with `/sard`.
Because the position of `/sard` is at 0.

Comment: Yea I saw it a little too late, but your suggestion will also allow `/bla/sard/bla` as url, don't know if that is something the OP wants. Also you have swapped your arguments, the $_SERVER var should be first.

Answer (score 1):

You mean utilize second segment to manipulate in your statements.

its better to use `explode` in this scenario.

```
$getURI     = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$expGetUri  = array_filter(explode("/", $getURI));
$secondSeg  = array_key_exists(1, $expGetUri) ? $expGetUri[1] : "";

switch($secondSeg) {
    case "sard" : //statements goes here
        break;
    case "otheruri" : //statements goes here
        break;
    default : //your default statement
}
```

Hope this would work fine.

**Terms used**

`array_filter` filters array with a callback, uses default callback as trim, know more on this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

`explode` (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) separates a string with a needle, and returns the array

`array_key_exists` the simplest one, self defining, checks whether the key/index exists in an array.